# Should be Quick Fix in Excel remove #NUM! from results

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, lookup

This is driving me bananas!

The code below is essentially a lookup that has more that one result that is displayed horizontally.

If there is no result I would like the cell to remain empty rather than displaying #NUM!

I have included "" to the IF clause but I am still getting #NUM! results

{=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$200, SMALL(*IF($A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$200, ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$200)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A$2))+1,""*), COLUMN(B1)))}

Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Embed you equation within an `IfError()` statement

Comment: works. cheers!!